# Where to hide ConnectionString while deployning an ASP.NET CORE 6 app on IIS with OrcleDb

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-core-6.0

I know this may have been asked here before. But I did a research and I failed to find what I am looking for.

I need a guide to store my ConnectionString with identity application pool while deploying an app on IIS.

I am using:
asp.net core 6 mvc
Oracle Database

Hiding it in secret.json while in development is simple enough, but hiding it while deployed into production seems to be the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ConnectionString in IIS manager. [image]
Refer to this official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/database-manager/use-the-database-manager.

This tutorial on Configure Data Source Settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-3-configure-data-source-settings.